# Rendering to Jade template. Backbone and Browserify

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, pug, browserify

I am trying to use a combination of Backbone, Jade and Browserify in my new app. As a test I am trying to render some content from my view to my Jade template. I get no error or no output to my template

main.jade

```
body
    script(type='template', id='test')

script(src!='{% static "js/bundle.js" %}')
```

app.js

```
window.$ = require('jquery');
var views = require('./dashboard/views');

views();
```

view.js

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var jade = require('jade');
Backbone.$ = $;

module.exports = function(){
    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            this.template = jade.compile($('#test').html());
        },

        render: function(){
            var html = this.template({item: 'hello world'});
            $('body').append(html);
        }
    });

    var test = new AppView();
    test.render()
};
```

Comment: So what's the question? Did you tried to console out something?